# RE-Assigning a task in SharePoint Workflow 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

Is there a way to Re-Assign a task to another user using SharePoint 2010 type workflow? As I have to reassign many due tasks of one user to another user. But I have noticed there isn't any such action such as "Re-Assign a task" in 2010 workflow.

Comment: what do you mean by "SharePoint 2010 type workflow". Do we talk about a workflow in SharePoint 2010? Or a specific (content) type workflow? And do we talk about SharePoint Designer / declarative workflow?

Comment: We have two options to create a workflow in SharePoint designer. One is 2010 workflow and second is 2013 workflow.

Comment: In this case my answer would be "no" for out of the box. One possibility is to design a custom action. But this needs programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature like `Re-Assign a task` in tasks list, This feature is available in Tasks Center in Project Server.

Meanwhile, You can update the task and set `Assigned To` field for the new user, but you should be aware of you can **only** reassign the tasks that are already assigned to you.

If you tried to reassign a task that is not assigned to you , you will get the following error

> Task update was not accepted. To edit a task associated with a
>   workflow task process, you must be the person to whom the task is
>   currently assigned.

So, you can allow multiple users to reassign other tasks that not assigned to them by setting `TaskProcessOwner` on `Start Task properties` to a specific group via SharePoint Designer

[image]

Now all users in `Qassas Group` can reassign the tasks that not assigned to them.